# Cant remote manage server "Access is denied"

Tags: remote-access, windows-server-2016, remote, performance-monitoring, windows-server-core

Im trying to work with performance monitor on windows server 2016 core. I have my PC a VM a new or was atleast new Installation of server core and i got some other VMs running. All im trying to do is access performance monior remotely.

So this is what i've tried

- Disabled all the firewalls
- Added the "LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy" in the regersty
- Did all the wsman and winrm commands on the local machine
- Added the admin account to performance log users and Performance Monitor Users groups. Just to make it worse i added all the user accounts i could find to those groups including everyone

Both of the pc are on the same workspace. Everytime i select a pc i get the error Access is denied. And i cant select as which use i want to log in. Which is the most frustrating part. I cant seem to pin down the problem it really does not tell a lot.